# Register and Forget links goes to different template in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla1.6

I am new to Joomla and this is my first project in Joomla. I am using Joomla 1.6 and for the login purposes I use the default **Login** plugin which comes with the Joomla 1.6. I am using Joomla 1.6 default template **Beez2-Default**. When I click with **Forget Password?** link or **Create an account** link the registration form or the forget password form is showing in another template in my case they're showing in **Beez2 - Parks Site**. But I need to show them in the same template **Beez2-Default**. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have logged in to the Joomla admin, in the Extensions menu, click on Template Manager. This should get you to the Styles manager. Find Beez2 - Parks Site and look in the "Assigned" column, there will probably be a green check mark. This means that the style has been assigned to a particular menu item. Click on the template and look in the Menu Assignment box, uncheck the menu items that you do not want to use the template on.

If this is not the case, then please provide a link to the site so we can see the error.